# How To Add Adblock Plus To Webbrowser Control?

Tags: c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control

How can I add Adblock Plus to a Webbrowser control?

*--- Or ---*

How can I block images and flash files in vb.net webbrowser?

I don't know how to use IWebBrowser2 + webbrowser to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Adblock plus is an extension (plugin) for Firefox and Chrome (and KMeleon). The .NET web browser control uses Internet Explorer, so I don't think this is going to be possible...

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Adblock IE](http://adblockie.codeplex.com/) and its source code.

You'll see that they developed a BHO ([Browser Helper Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object)) and handle certain events like "Document completed" which you could handle in the `WebBrowserControl`, too.

So basically, if I would have to develop such a thing, I would base my code on that Adblock IE source code and adjust it to work with the WebBrowserControl.

Comment: @chikanidipan Simply click the first link of my answer. You'll find everything on the project's page over there.

Comment: [A Free and Simple Solution:] Adding host file using threading @ vb.net.Done!